# HTML: What would I put in between for the label for""

Tags: html

I'm getting an error as I tried using compturnon as the label for, but it didn't work can anyone let me know what it should be? If I put yes it works but I'm not sure if that's totally correct.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fix This - Computer Repair Reporting</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/assets/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/assets/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/assets/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/assets/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/assets/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/assets/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/assets/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/assets/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header><h1>Computer Repair Reporting</h1></header>
        <form action="http://webdevbasics.net/scripts/demo.php" method="post">
            <div>
                <p>There are several methods for reporting a problem at problem to ITS, the easiest way
                is the fill out the form below and submit it to ITS. If you need immediate assistance or are not able to describe the issue, please call <i>1-888-FIX-THIS.</i></p>
            </div>
            <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend><strong>Personal Information</strong></legend>
            <div class="spacings">
                <label for="fullname">Full Name:</label>
                <input id="fullname" name="fullname" type="text" placeholder="First and last name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="spacings">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="jsmith@gmail.com" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
                <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="(###) ###-####" required>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend><strong>Fix It Information</strong></legend>
            <div class="spacings">
                <label for="room">Select Your Room:</label>
                <select id="room" name="room" required>
                    <option disabled selected value="">
                        Choose a room
                    </option>
                    <option value="S308">
                        S308
                    </option>
                    <option value="S324">
                        S324
                    </option>
                    <option value="L2">
                        L2
                    </option>
                    <option value="ME201">
                        ME201
                    </option>
                    <option value="ME208">
                        ME208
                    </option>
                </select><br>
            </div>
            <div class="spacings">
                <label for="machinenum">Select Your Machine Number (1 - 15): </label>
                <input id="machinenum" name="machinenum" type="number" min="1" max="15" value="" placeholder="#" required><br>
            </div>
            <div class="spacings">
                <p>Does the computer turn on?</p>
                <input  id="yes" name="compturnon" type="radio" value="yes" required>
                <label for="yes">Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                <input  id="no" name="compturnon" type="radio" value="no">
                <label for="no">No&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
            </div>
            <div class="spacings">
                <label for="reportdate">Reporting Date:</label>
                <input id="reportdate" name="reportdate" type="date" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="message">Brief Description of Problem(s):</label><br>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="50" rows="5" placeholder="Please indicate the problem(s) you are experiencing" required></textarea> 
            </div>
            </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Please submit this form and we will attempt to get the issue fixed within 12 hours.</p>
            </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Fix me">
                <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
    </div>
        <footer>
        <small>&copy; 2016 Michael Manieri</small>
        </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body, input[type=submit], input[type=reset] {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
}

h1 {
    color:#E60957;
    font-size:35px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    text-align: center;
}

input[type=submit], input[type=reset]{
    background:#E60957;
    border:2px solid #E60957;
    border-radius:15px;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:5px 15px;
}

input[type=submit]:hover, input[type=reset]:hover {
    background-color:#B73F69;
    border:none;
}

fieldset {
    border-color:#E60957;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    width:545px;
}

legend {
    color:#E60957;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

#container, footer {
    margin:25px auto;
    width:575px;
}

.spacings {
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

Comment: The `id` of the `input` you want it to focus on. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#attr-for

Comment: @Luke but there are two different id's yes and no for the same question.

Comment: The label at the top cannot have one `id` in that case. It's only capable of focusing one element, so remove the `for` attribute from the first `label`, and keep it on the last two.

Comment: Don't give it a `for` value

Comment: @Luke even though I removed it and when I did have it on yes. The answer once I click the button for my form is always Yes

Comment: I have removed the for value but it's still not working right its validated but not correct

Comment: No, because the value of your `no` input is _yes_

Comment: @LGSon omg.. sorry about the rookie mistake thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, change the second input's value to `no`.

Second, replace the first `label` with a `fieldset`/`legend`, and since you used a fieldset already, this one does not have a border and set your legend color back to black

```css
fieldset.borderless {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
fieldset.borderless legend {
  color: black;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="borderless">
  <legend>Does the computer turn on</legend>
  <input id="yes" name="compturnon" type="radio" value="yes" required>
  <label for="yes">Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
  <input id="no" name="compturnon" type="radio" value="no">
  <label for="no">No&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
</fieldset>
```

Here is you original code, updated

```css
body,
input[type=submit],
input[type=reset] {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
h1 {
  color: #E60957;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}
input[type=submit],
input[type=reset] {
  background: #E60957;
  border: 2px solid #E60957;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
input[type=submit]:hover,
input[type=reset]:hover {
  background-color: #B73F69;
  border: none;
}
fieldset {
  border-color: #E60957;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  width: 545px;
}
legend {
  color: #E60957;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#container,
footer {
  margin: 25px auto;
  width: 575px;
}
.spacings {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

fieldset.borderless {
  border: none;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
fieldset.borderless legend {
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Computer Repair Reporting</h1>
  </header>
  <form action="http://webdevbasics.net/scripts/demo.php" method="post">
    <div>
      <p>There are several methods for reporting a problem at problem to ITS, the easiest way is the fill out the form below and submit it to ITS. If you need immediate assistance or are not able to describe the issue, please call <i>1-888-FIX-THIS.</i>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <fieldset>
        <legend><strong>Personal Information</strong>
        </legend>
        <div class="spacings">
          <label for="fullname">Full Name:</label>
          <input id="fullname" name="fullname" type="text" placeholder="First and last name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="spacings">
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="jsmith@gmail.com" required>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
          <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="(###) ###-####" required>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div>
      <fieldset>
        <legend><strong>Fix It Information</strong>
        </legend>
        <div class="spacings">
          <label for="room">Select Your Room:</label>
          <select id="room" name="room" required>
            <option disabled selected value="">
              Choose a room
            </option>
            <option value="S308">
              S308
            </option>
            <option value="S324">
              S324
            </option>
            <option value="L2">
              L2
            </option>
            <option value="ME201">
              ME201
            </option>
            <option value="ME208">
              ME208
            </option>
          </select>
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="spacings">
          <label for="machinenum">Select Your Machine Number (1 - 15):</label>
          <input id="machinenum" name="machinenum" type="number" min="1" max="15" value="" placeholder="#" required>
          <br>
        </div>
        <fieldset class="spacings borderless">
          <legend>Does the computer turn on</legend>
          <input id="yes" name="compturnon" type="radio" value="yes" required>
          <label for="yes">Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
          <input id="no" name="compturnon" type="radio" value="no">
          <label for="no">No&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="spacings">
          <label for="reportdate">Reporting Date:</label>
          <input id="reportdate" name="reportdate" type="date" required>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="message">Brief Description of Problem(s):</label>
          <br>
          <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="50" rows="5" placeholder="Please indicate the problem(s) you are experiencing" required></textarea>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Please submit this form and we will attempt to get the issue fixed within 12 hours.</p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Fix me">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  </form>
</div>
<footer>
  <small>&copy; 2016 Michael Manieri</small>
</footer>
```

Comment: Even with fixing up the color and stuff it's ever so slightly out of line I tried text-align:left; and that didn't help. I'm gonna post the whole code and css check my original post in a moment.

Comment: Forgot to mention, not sure if that notifies you.

Comment: @Mibby Updated my answer with an updated version of your code

Comment: I saw it but just as a quick question would <p> be able to work as well or no?

Comment: @Mibby Practically yes, semantically no ... and there is many who prefer practically :) ... and if you do to, I recommend, in this case, using a `div` instead of a `p`

Comment: I have everything div'd off as is per question per fieldset etc

Comment: @Mibby Use a `div` if you need a block element, `span` if inline ... assumed we talk practically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126421/discussion-between-mibby-and-lgson).

Comment: I started a chat in hopes we can continue this in chat, almost done!

Comment: @Mibby Its bedtime here, so post your question and I'll have a look tomorrow

Comment: Would this also be correct? prntscr.com/cxorr2 
I have it in a div but <p> around the sentence I cant use a label for

Answer (score 1):

Per [MDN’s `<label>` docs](http://attr-for):

> #### `for`
>
> The ID of a labelable form-related element in the same document as the label element. The first such element in the document with an ID matching the value of the `for` attribute is the *labeled control* for this label element.
>
> A label element can have both a `for` attribute and a contained control element, as long as the `for` attribute points to the contained control element.

---

Though if you want to “label” more than one field, you should wrap them in a [`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) and use a [`<legend>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend). E.g.

```
<fieldset class="spacings">
  <legend>Does the computer turn on</legend>

  <input id="yes" name="compturnon" type="radio" value="yes" required>
  <label for="yes">Yes</label>
  <input id="no" name="compturnon" type="radio" value="yes">
  <label for="no">No</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: This is all apart of a fieldset this is just one bit of my code that is not working.

Comment: @Mibby Nested `<fieldset>`s is valid. But you cannot have a `<label>` be associated with more than one field.

Comment: Ill have to do all sorts of extra work if I use a nested fieldset because I have css on my fieldsets already so once I make that a fieldset it's gonna be bigger, red, etc etc

Comment: It doesn't persay have to be a "label" I just need it to stay how it is http://prntscr.com/cxo0z0

Comment: @Mibby So then change the style? HTML ≠ CSS.

Comment: Can you check my last post under LGSon's answers?

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="spacings">
     <span>Does the computer turn on?</span>
     <input  id="compturnon_yes" name="compturnon" type="radio" value="yes" />
     <label for="computernon_yes">Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
     <input id="computernon_no" name="compturnon" type="radio" value="yes" />
     <label for="computernon_no" name="compturnon" type="radio" value="no">No</label>
</div>
```

Would be an example of correct usage of the "label" tag and its "for" attribute -- The "for" attribute is used to specify the ID of the element to which the label applies; each "for" attribute make must reference a unique form element.

In your case you have not defined such an element.

For more information, see: https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label

Comment: That was not clear from the question -- Instead then wrap it in another element designed to contain text. ("span", for instance). [See above]. 

If you post the entirety of the markup for your form, then a more holistic answer could be delivered.

Comment: @Mibby — Then you just need to change your first label into a legend element.

Comment: Is span not able to be used here?

Comment: @Mibby Semantically no, practically yes, though if you need it to be positioned _above_ your label/input, use a div. I posted a new answer for you that might help achieving both semantic and layout

Comment: @LGSon Check the comments on your answer, it isn't letting me tag you for some reason.

Comment: You don't need to tag comments to the user who posted an answer, she/he always get notified